# Calculations with COUNT()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset I can group and want to know the percentage of rows in each group.

This seems to nearly works, except that it returns 0 for every group because of imho missing typecast

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(name) 
                    FROM x 
                    WHERE d = '0') 
  FROM x, y 
  WHERE x.a = y.a AND x.b = '0' 
  GROUP BY y.c 
  ORDER BY y.c ASC
```

How do I correctly cast this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than multiplying by `1.0`, you could just cast.  That seems cleaner and clearer to me.  For one thing, it makes clear what data type you want to use.  You may be happy enough with the precision of `float4` or `float8` approximations, rather than paying the extra cost for the exact `numeric` calculations.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)::float / (SELECT COUNT(name) 
                           FROM x 
                           WHERE d = '0')::float
  FROM x, y 
  WHERE x.a = y.a AND x.b = '0' 
  GROUP BY y.c 
  ORDER BY y.c ASC
```

```
test=# select 1.0 * 5 / 10;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 0.50000000000000000000
(1 row)

test=# select pg_typeof(1.0 * 5 / 10);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 numeric
(1 row)

test=# select 5::float / 10::float;
 ?column? 
----------
      0.5
(1 row)

test=# select pg_typeof(5::float / 10::float);
    pg_typeof     
------------------
 double precision
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do

```
select 1.0 * count(*) / .....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert to `float` your problem might be solved:

```
SELECT convert(double, COUNT(*)) / (SELECT convert(double, COUNT(name)) 
                    FROM x 
                    WHERE d = '0') 
  FROM x, y 
  WHERE x.a = y.a AND x.b = '0' 
  GROUP BY y.c 
  ORDER BY y.c ASC
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "float" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT convert(float, COUNT(*)) / (SELECT convert(float, COU...